# Double angle bracket mode

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

I'm using PowerShell 7.1.3 and have noticed a strange behavior when entering a single quote to my prompt:

```
PS: '
>>
>>
```

The prompt is styled with `>>` and no matter what I type, nothing gets executed (or that's how it looks). I was wondering:

- Is this activated by entering `'` on the shell, or is this a side effect?
- Is this mode called somehow?
- Is this mode useful for a specific case?

Comment: It's multiline mode. PowerShell is smart enough to let you finish your multiline string. Just enter closing comma to finish. You can actually switch to this mode at any time using `Shift+Enter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this activated by entering `'` on the shell, or is this a side effect?

It's an *intentional* side-effect of entering an unmatched `'` as a command, yes.

It's technically not PowerShell itself, but rather the [PSReadLine](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine) module (which ships with PowerShell 7 and is enabled by default).

PSReadLine provides a number of command line editing improvements - including syntax highlighting, customizable tab- and menu-completion, and **multi-line editing** - and it works by continously feeding your (partial) input to [PowerShell's *parser*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.parser?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0), and then uses the results returned by the parser to provide the correct syntax highlighting etc.

So when you press `[Enter]` after having typed a single `'`, PSReadLine sends your input to the parser like this:

```
# Parse the input script the same way PSReadLine would
$ParserErrors = @()
$AST = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput("'", [ref]$null, [ref]$ParserErrors)

# Let's inspect any parser errors 
$ParserErrors
```

If you run this in PowerShell 7.1.3, you'll see the following errors were reported:

```
Extent ErrorId                         Message                                  IncompleteInput
------ -------                         -------                                  ---------------
'      TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString The string is missing the terminator: '.            True
```

Notice the last property of the error, `IsInputIncomplete` - PSReadLine sees that what you've typed in the prompt is *incomplete* - and it therefore assumes you're not done writing your command and continues the prompt on the next line for you.

> [...] no matter what I type, nothing gets executed

That's not quite true - if you enter something that *completes* the input (eg. makes it valid PowerShell again), it'll let you submit it - in your case that would be by typing a closing `'`:

[image: PSReadLine prompt continuation behavior for Incomplete Input]

> Is this mode called somehow?

No idea, I tend to think of `>>` as a "prompt continuation indicator", but it's not really a distinct *mode* per se.

> Is this mode useful for a specific case?

Well, as shown above it prevents you from trying to execute syntactically invalid or incomplete code, that's pretty useful in itself I think.

The overall ability to do multi-line editing *at the prompt* is, in my personal opinion, one of the **biggest strengths of PowerShell** - you can start prototyping small functions and compose quite complex pipelines without having to switch back and forth between an editor.

As [beatcracker mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67130115/double-angle-bracket-mode/67130669#comment118658983_67130115), you can also get prompt continuation (at least in the default Windows Console Host) by pressing `Shift+Enter` - this works regardless of whether the existing input is incomplete or not.

You can basically *write and edit a whole script at the prompt* if you wanted to.

Comment: Another awesome answer. Very informative. +1